# MVC4 Foreign Key constraint prevents posting insert to SQL db

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-database-first

Using MVC4 I'm trying to insert a column into a linking table that has a two column composite key. Both columns are primary key in two separate tables.

Key1 is picked up from a hidden field in the web form which is generated from an id passed in the URL.

Key2 is the selected value picked up from a dropdown list of names from the second PK table.

As far as I can tell, the values are correct (they appear in the two primary key tables).

Does anyone know why I'm getting an error from the HttpPost Create action (mainly default scaffolding code) that tells me there is a conflict with the first PK -> FK constraint?

Comment: Does the hidden input field have a name attribute. If it doesn't then it won't be posted and then the value of key1 will default to zero which will throw that exception.

Comment: the hidden input has name, id, and value fields which appear be correct (e.g. "id", "id", "2")

Comment: When you debug the create model - are the correct values being passed back?  - would help to include some basic code...

Comment: @PeterH it throws the error before it hits the debugger. I didn't want to include code so as not to skew the direction people might come from with suggestions. The only change I've made to the scaffolded code is to comment out the viewbag for a dropdown on the PK1 field and add the 'int id' parameter to the Create method on the  controller. The html shows the correct value for the hidden field. All I can think of is that the routes are not sending the id to the correct table/column and a null is being captured from somewhere between posting and the sql insert.

Comment: So key1 is being passed back - and key2 is being set by the hidden field.  Can you verify that key2 is coming back into the create method in the controller?  What does your create sig look like?

Comment: ah, thanks for the nudge - both keys were being picked up but the first wasn't being handled properly before the db.saveChanges() - couldn't see the wood for the trees - simple noob error now that I've seen it... still not sure why the debugger didn't pick it up though; could that be an MVC thing?

Comment: pls post the EXACT and FULL error which you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error here was caused by the naming of the "id" in the controller. Need to remember when I'm accessing database values vs returning view values. Can we put it down to lack of sleep and a medical ban on caffiene?